# SolR float (TrieFloatField) storage limits

Tags: php, solr, binary, floating-point

I'm trying to understand how float are stored in SolR.
I have a delta between the float value in PHP (32-bit) and the stored one in SolR.

I've searched in the documentation, "Field Types Included with SolR" :

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Field+Types+Included+with+Solr

And found for TrieFloatField:

> Floating point field (32-bit IEEE floating point). precisionStep="0"
>   enables efficient numeric sorting and minimizes index size;
>   precisionStep="8" (the default) enables efficient range queries.

But I don't know how to estimate what will be the stored value.
Here are some tests I've made.
The value I've tried to insert in the float field and the result:

```
ok: 2097151.1
ko: 2097152.1 -> 2097152
ko: 20971521 -> 20971520
ok: 16777216
ko: 16777217 -> 16777216
ko: 4294967296 -> 4294967300
ok: 4294967300
ko: 4294967301 -> 4294967300
```

I don't understand which constraint is used, it is not rounded.
Maybe it is a binary constraint, because it looks like it is rounded to fit powers of 2.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two#The_first_96_powers_of_two

```
2^21 = 2,097,152
2^24 = 16,777,216
2^32 = 4,294,967,296
```

As you can see, these values are close the the ones stored by SolR.

Does someone have an idea how SolR stores float?
And how to evaluate it with PHP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the most secure way to compare floats is to use pack().
Pack data into binary string to securely compare two floats.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#119860

So, as an alternative to using

```
$float1 === $float2
```

one could use

```
pack('f', $float1) === pack ('f', $float2)
```

with a big footnote that one should really remember that one is *reducing* your accuracy of the comparison. AFAIK is this the only way (apart from epsilon methods) to securely compare two floats.

Answer (score 0):

As you've mentioned, it's a 32 bit floating point number. A 32-bit floating point number can't represent all the values between 0 and 2^32 exactly, so there will be inaccuracies and numbers that can't be represented using those bits.

You can use a converter like [IEEE754 Floating Point Conversion](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) to test the values you've included, and they all convert to what you're getting back from Solr.

Floating point numbers are not exact, and aren't magic - there's still just 2^32 distinct values available, so when you're trying to store values that don't map exactly onto the possible values that a 32 bit FP can represent, you'll get inaccuracies.

Doubles were introduced to have more accuracy (64-bit vs 32-bit), and you can use doubles in Solr by using a TrieDoubleField instead.

Another option, depending on what you need, is to use a long field instead, and multiplying by 10 or 100 when storing a value and dividing the value on the way out. That will allow you to exactly represent a decimal number with two digits after the dot.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try transpose this JavaScript example in PHP.

Comment: Ho, I di not see that your link is in fact using a .py file... So I had to search by myself.